# cocos2d: change CCMenuItemImage when mouse passes over?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, mouseover, ccmenuitem, ccmenu

Does anyone know of an easy way to animate a CCMenuItem when the mouse passes over it.

I have read this thread:

[Cocos2d CCMenuItem  animation upon selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10475623/1443375)

which seems to cover Cocoa Touch but does not work for me with OS X.

The cocos2d reference lists this method of CCMenuItemImage: which I used this way:

```
CCMenuItem *beginButtonMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"BeginButton3.png" 
                                                     selectedImage:@"BeginButtonSel3.png"
                                                            target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(beginButtonPressed:)];
```

However that menu item does not respond by changing the image when the mouse passes over, only when clicked.

the CCMenuItem reference has this method:

- (void) selected, stating "The item was selected (not activated), similar to "mouse-over""

but has no sample code ...

Can anyone help implement this?

Thanks

Comment: CCMenu really isn't that flexible. You're usually better off to create your own animated button class instead of hacking CCMenu's code.

Comment: can you briefly sketch how to do that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it to be quite easy to make the `CCMenu` change any `CCMenuItem` to the `selected` state when the mouse passes over it, giving it a hover effect. First, make sure you've set `[window_ setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];`

Then add this function to `CCMenu.m` (perhaps just after `ccMouseDragged` definition):

```
- (BOOL) ccMouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event {
  if( ! _visible || ! _enabled)
    return NO;

  CCMenuItem *currentItem = [self itemForMouseEvent:event];
  if(!currentItem) {
    if(_highlightedItem != _selectedItem) {
      [_highlightedItem unselected];
    }
    [_highlightedItem release];
    _highlightedItem = nil;
    return NO;
  }

  if (currentItem != _highlightedItem) {
    [_highlightedItem unselected];
    _highlightedItem = currentItem;
    [_highlightedItem retain];
    [_highlightedItem selected];
  }

  return YES;
}
```